# Django admin page. When i run the server everything will be fine, but when i try log into the admin page i will lose my connection

Tags: django, python-3.x

Am getting back the last line after i navigate to the 127.0.0.1:8000/admin

**the browser message**

This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**my terminal message**

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\bin\runnerw64.exe" C:\Users\UCHE\PycharmProjects\blog\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/UCHE/PycharmProjects/blog/manage.py runserver 8000
Performing system checks...
Watching for file changes with StatReloader

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 16, 2020 - 22:15:50
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'blog.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 19
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2136
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:34] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:34] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:35] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:35] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:35] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:35] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:36] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:36] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2020 22:16:49] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a super user, ? If you haven't  created a super user create  one and login to admin of django project.
Use following  comand to create a super user

python manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I have migrated and i have created a super user. i am following a tutorial video and i did everything on the video, i even updated django and the IDE (pycharm) i am using